# Can't display selecteditem

Tags: wpf, xaml, selecteditem

My combobox display all my datas correctly in the list, but the selected item is not displayed, instead of i just have the name of my object.

It worked fine without the item template, but i need it to display my data. Did i do something wrong? How can get my selected items display in the same dataTemplate?

```
<ComboBox Grid.Row="2" 
          Grid.Column="1" 
          Style="{StaticResource myComboBox}" 
          x:Name="ComboBoxProtocole" 
          IsEditable="True" 
          IsTextSearchEnabled="True"
          TextSearch.Text="labelFull"
          ItemsSource="{Binding}"
          >
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding labelShort}" FontSize="12"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding labelFull}" FontSize="10" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: What is itemsSource bound to?

Comment: It is bound to my datacontext, an observable collection of my object

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the  TextSearch.TextPath="labelFull"

```
<ComboBox Grid.Row="2" 
      Grid.Column="1"           
      x:Name="ComboBoxProtocole" 
      IsEditable="True" 
      IsTextSearchEnabled="True"
      TextSearch.TextPath="labelFull"
      ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding labelShort}" FontSize="12"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding labelFull}" FontSize="10" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>
```

Comment: TextPath it was, mymistake didn't see that !